# Why is my code working in Firefox (Greasemonkey) but not in Chrome (Tampermonkey)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, instagram, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have used some code to automatically follow someone on Instagram in Greasemonkey but when I try it in Tampermonkey in Chrome I get a symbol with an exclamation mark saying 'filterArrButtons' is not defined.

Here is the code

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("_5f5mN");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  if (btns[i].innerHTML == "Follow") {
    btns[i].click();
  }
}
    for (var x = 0; x <= filterArrButtons.length - 1; x++) {
      var df = filterArrButtons[x].classList;
      df = df.value.split(" ");
      simulateCliks(filterArrButtons[x], "click");
    }
  }, 2000);

});

function simulateCliks(el, evntType) {
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + evntType);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(evntType, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}

});
```

And here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9fu.jpg)

I've tried searching for an answer to the problem I'm getting but I can't find anything. It works in Greasemonkey on Firefox but not in Tampermonkey in Chrome.

Comment: `filterArrButtons` isn't defined anywhere in the posted code so I guess you're trying to use a variable defined by the page? Maybe the script in Chrome doesn't have `@grant none`

Answer (score 1):

**run-at**
GreaseMonkey and ViolentMonkey defaults to `'document-end'` while the Firefox content_scripts default run-at is `'document_idle'` and so does FireMonkey and TamperMonkey.

```
GreaseMonkey        document-end
ViolentMonkey       document-end

FireMonkey          document-idle
TamperMonkey        document-idle
```

`document-idle` in TamperMonkey means that script is injected AFTER `'DOMContentLoaded'`, therefore `'DOMContentLoaded'` will never fire the event.

The complete script is not shown so it is unclear if `run-at` is set or left as default.